# Why do we need a default constructor to pass an object by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, default, required

My C++ compiler give me an error "no default constructor exists for class Foo" when I try the following.

MyClass::MyClass(const Foo& foo)
{
...
}

If I'm passing a reference, the object should already be initialized, correct? And it's not a problem with copy constructors, because I defined one explicitly. So why would one need a default constructor to pass a reference?

The only thing I've been able to think of is that it might not know how much memory to allocate for it. If that's the problem, is there a way to tell the compiler that I only ever intend to allocate this object dynamically? I haven't been able to find any answers online for this, and I would really appreciate some help.

EDIT: I'm just going to edit in my actual code.

MemberManager.cpp:

```
#include "MemberManager.h"

MemberManager::MemberManager(const NodeManager& nodeSet, std::vector<int> cctMat, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        memSet[i] = Member();
    }
}
```

NodeManager.h

```
#include "Node.h"

class NodeManager
{
public:
    //constructors
    NodeManager(std::vector<double> crdMat, std::vector<Constraint> cstMat, int n):
        nodeSet(n) {};
    //copy
    NodeManager(const NodeManager& src):
        nodeSet(src.nodeSet) {};
}
```

My precise error message is a red underline under the first body bracket of MemberManager::MemberManager(...) and it says no default constructor exists for NodeManager. This is my intent, but I don't understand WHY it would need a default constructor.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: You should also add the [tag:c++] tag, like I did.

Comment: You have shown a constructor for `MyClass` that takes a `Foo` as input. What kind of constructor(s) does `Foo` have? When you get the error, what does the call to that `MyClass` constructor look like? The compiler is trying to tell you that you are passing something that it can't construct a `Foo` for.

Comment: The extremely short code sample you've posted is fine: http://ideone.com/zHgTLp . Please edit in enough code to replicate this issue. I suspect you are trying to default construct a `Foo` somwhere.

Comment: I've already provided in the OP all the context that actually exists in my program so far. I only have the one constructor, and the only method in MyClass so far, and Foo's constructor is never called, default or otherwise.

Comment: @Bbqsauce The link I've posted shows that the code in your OP **compiles**. Please edit in enough code to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a default constructor to pass an object by reference. Your code must be doing something else that requires such a thing.

My guess is that `MyClass` has a member of type `Foo`. If it isn't default-constructible, then it needs to be initialised in its declaration, or in the constructor's initialiser list:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const Foo& foo) : foo(foo) { ... }
                                   ^^^^^^^^
                                   initialiser list
```

This assumes that the member is called `foo`, and that it's supposed to be initalised by copying the function parameter.

Comment: I would upvote you if I could. This was, indeed, the issue but I was confused by where the error was displayed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what compiler you are using, which standard of c++ it complies to and if you have other constructors for `MyClass`.

What I can imagine is that the compiler does not generate a default constructor `MyClass()` because you have defined another constructor.  Should the compiler ever want to generate a default object of `class MyClass` like in

```
class MyClass mc;
```

The only way to accomplish this in the absence of `MyClass::MyClass()` is to think the code line above as

```
class MyClass mc( Foo() );
```

This requires `class Foo` to have a default constructor.

I would have made this a comment,  but I'm not yet allowed to.

Comment: I'm using visual studio express 2013 with c++11. The error does not occur when I call the MyClass constructor, it just red-underlines the first bracket of the body. I haven't called anything yet. MyClass:MyClass(const Foo& foo)s also the only constructor so far and the only method in the class.

Comment: To verify if my thesis above is right,  could you add a default constructor for MyClass?  Even if this does not make sense for your class,  there are a variety of non-obvious occasions when a default constructor is used and you may find that you need one.